# Functor $F_p(G)=\{g\in G: g \text{ has order } 1 \text{ or } p\}$ is representable

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Consider a group $G$ and let $p$ be a prime number. Define the functor $F_p:\operatorname{Grp}\to \operatorname{Set}$ as $$F_p(G):=\{g\in G: g\text{ has order } 1\text{ or } p\}.$$ We will use $|g|$ to denote the order of $g\in G$. Show that $F_p$ is representable.

We need to find a group $H$ such that $F_p(G)\cong \operatorname{hom}_{\operatorname{Grp}}(H,G)$ for all $G\in\operatorname{Grp}$ (this is an isomorphism in the category of sets, in other words, a bijection).

Let's first consider $G=C_p$ the cyclic group of order $p$. Then $F_p(G)=C_p$. We want to find a group $H$ such that $C_p\cong \operatorname{hom}_{\operatorname{Grp}}(H,C_p)$. So there must be a group homomorphism $\alpha:H\to C_p$ such that $$\forall \beta\in \operatorname{hom}_{\operatorname{Grp}}(H,C_p): \exists i\in\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}:\beta=\alpha^i.$$ Let $x\in H$. If $\alpha(x)\ne 1$, then $|\alpha(x)|=p \mid |x|$. If $\alpha(x)=1$, then $x\in \ker\alpha$, and $|\ker\alpha| \mid p$, but then $\ker\alpha=1$ or $\ker\alpha\cong C_p$, so either $x=1$ or $|x|=p$. The non-trivial elements of $H$ have therefore order $p$ or order $p^ld$ for some $p\not\mid d$ and $l\ge0$ (with $d$ and $l$ depending on the element of course). Because $\operatorname{im}\alpha$ is a subgroup of $C_p$, we must have $\operatorname{im}\alpha\in\{1,C_p\}$. If $\ker\alpha=1$, then $\operatorname{im}\alpha=C_p$, hence $H\cong C_p$; if $\ker\alpha\cong C_p$, then $\operatorname{im}\alpha =1$, and again $H\cong C_p$. But this $H$ clearly depends on the group $C_p$ that we have chosen to consider as a special case.

How can we find an $H$ so that the isomorphism holds for all groups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, now you found a good candidate for $H$, why don't you fix once and for all a specific incarnation of $C_p$, and show that it does the job ?

For example, set $H=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Then, show that the map $\varphi_G:g\in F_p(G)\mapsto (\bar{m}\in H\mapsto g^m\in G)\in Hom(H,G)$ is well defined and bijective (check first that the map on the right is a well defined group morphism from $H$to $G$)

Nex, check that it is it functorial in $G$ and you are done.